# VIX OTM put options decrease value after sharp decrease of underlying

Tags: options, greeks, vix

I was wondering about disentangling an effect I saw on the market yesterday. I saw nearly all OTM VIX put options with maturity date 15/04/2020 decrease in value while at the same time the VIX took a sharp downfall. What would you give as possible reasons given current market conditions? And, how would you investigate such effects to understand it?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the VIX took a sharp downfall on 2020/03/02, from 40.11 to 33.42 (-6.69).

But that is not what the 2020/04/15 Put options are based on, they are based on the 2020/04/15 VIX Futures (VIJ20), these went from 23.025 on 2020/02/28 to 23.325 on 2020/03/02 an **increase** of 0.3.

The Vix options are based on the futures, not the spot Vix value.

Comment: Interesting and stupid of me, I will consider the futures 'term structure' if one can call it like that in the future.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe implied vol on the VIX fell. An option can lose value even if the underlying goes in its direction if implied volatility falls enough to outweigh the directional effect.

Comment: Implied vol is a measure you calculate after seeing market prices to calibrate prices to a model you assume; so yeah if you calibrate it to the new price it will change but yeah.. that doesnt explain anything?

Comment: So what do you think it means when implied vol changes? Its just meaningless? Vega too? How would you then explain a call option decreasing in value as the underlying increases?

Comment: Well yes, given that we assume a certain model these can explain it, but I was more looking for some model free insights.

Comment: on "is it meaningless": well it depends, if the fitted stochastic process that is implied by the model is totally wrong for the VIX, I would say considering implied vol can be meaningless yes.